# Yii2 redirect all urls to https://www without using htaccess

Tags: yii2

I need to be able to redirect all urls (non www and www) to https://www in Yii2.

I want to try to do this without using .htaccess

It's not a problem to create the urls via the urlManager in Components:

```
urlManager => [
    'baseUrl' => 'https://www.somesite.com'
]
```

However, I'm struggling to do the redirects. I did take a look at this article http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages - does that help in the context of Yii2?

**EDIT**

I made reference in my comment below that when I added $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on' in the backend folder index.php, I get SSL without having to do anything with the .htaccess file which is great. This is used in the function getIsSecureConnection() in \yii2\web\Request.php

This was referenced in this article https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9116

However, if I do the same on the frontend index.php file, I do not get the same behaviour.

For example

http://www.client-site-1.co.uk/backend => https://www.client-site-1.co.uk/backend

(I don't have a SSL on this domain at the moment!)

versus

http://www.client-site-1.co.uk => http://www.client-site-1.co.uk

Any help much appreciated !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

Comment: Hi, I know there are a lot of htaccess redirect questions - I wanted to make this specific to Yii2, not having to use .htaccess at all

Comment: Hi, I am using the advanced template. In the backend, I've just added $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on' to the index.php file. That did the trick! However, on the front end, doing the same does not produce the same result ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution which is what I need on Yii2

[Force HTTPS on Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561440/force-https-on-yii2), extending the Yii application class

All the credit goes to [plm57](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3402681/plm57)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it with Apache without .htaccess
#
# Non www 
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    # Other alternatives domains:
    ServerAlias example.net www.example.net
    ServerAlias example.org www.example.org

    RedirectPermanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>


#
# Main site - www
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/frontend/web
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this - however, I want to do it directly using Yii2 - have solution for this now